# variable via SSH session

Tags: shell, ssh, environment-variables

mount.cifs can use the variable PASSWD for password authentication.

Well, the following example show the problem:

```
export PASSWD=mysecret; ssh foreignhost "echo $PASSWD"
```

works, it means, the value of the environment variable PASSWD will be shown. Well,

```
export PASSWD=mysecret; ssh foreignhost "mount -t cifs //server/path /mnt -o username=myuser"
```

is asking for a password, but

```
export PASSWD=mysecret; ssh foreignhost "PASSWD=$PASSWD mount -t cifs //server/path /mnt -o username=myuser"
```

don't ask for a password but uses the value of PASSWD for authentication. But why? The security concern is the fact, that password will be shown in cleartext in a process list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
export PASSWD=mysecret; ssh foreignhost "echo $PASSWD"
```

This sets the shell variable `PASSWD` in your local shell (and also in the environment of subprocesses started by your local shell). This then executes the command `echo mysecret` on `foreignhost`. In `"echo $PASSWD"`, the local shell performs variable expansion on the text between the double quotes. The password string appears in the command line of the remote shell, so it's visible in the process list.

```
export PASSWD=mysecret; ssh foreignhost "mount -t cifs //server/path /mnt -o username=myuser"
```

This sets the shell variable `PASSWD` in your local shell (and also in the environment of subprocesses started by your local shell, including the `ssh` client process. Depending on the client and the server's configuration, the SSH client may transmit certain environment variables to the server, and the server may or may not accept them. Typically, only a few whitelisted environment variables are forwarded through SSH: the local variables `LANG` and `LC_*` (plus `TERM` which gets special treatment). Unless you (or your distribution) has configured both the SSH client to send `PASSWD` and the SSH server to accept `PASSWD`, the remote shell does not have the environment variable `PASSWD` set.

```
export PASSWD=mysecret; ssh foreignhost "PASSWD=$PASSWD mount -t cifs //server/path /mnt -o username=myuser"
```

As in the first case, the remote shell command has the password (`PASSWD=mysecret mount …`) and so it's visible in the process list.

---

Many distributions configure SSH to send and accept all environment variables whose name matches `LC_*`, so you can forward data by defining your own.

```
LC_ENV_PASSWD=mysecret ssh foreignhost 'export PASSWD="$LC_ENV_PASSWD"; mount …'
```

Note the single quotes around the argument to `ssh`. This way, the shell command executed on the remote host is `export PASSWD="$LC_ENV_PASSWD"; mount …`, which does not contain the password.

Alternatively, pass the password on standard input.

```
echo mysecret | ssh foreignhost 'IFS= read -r PASSWD; export PASSWD; mount …'
```